# Some of the values in Table is wrong in my published paper

Tags: publications

In my survey paper (50 pages), I directly quote the results of performance from related papers. However, several numbers are wrongly recorded. My survey focuses on the introudction and summarization of current methods and the performance analysis takes very little portion (2 pages). Also, these mistakes do not affect the summarization in the survey.

Do I need to correct them by a erratum？

Comment: Probably not. Ask the editor of the journal that published the paper.